# How to name newly added table columns generated by vlook up

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I used the below codes to generate some new columns to the table using vlookup. How could I name the new columns as well as their current names are column 1, column 2, column 3 etc. Thank you very much!

```
Columns("A").Delete

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[+1]=""PAYING"",         VLOOKUP(RC[-30],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R20000C8,8,0),""PENDING"")"

Range("AF2:AF" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-31],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R20000C8,2,0), ""PENDING"")"

Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(LEN(RC[-31])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-31], "";"", """"))+1)*1200"

Range("AH2:AH" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-33],'Sheet3'!R2C2:R220C4,2,0)"

Range("AI2:AI" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-34],'Sheet3'!R2C2:R220C4,3,0)"

Columns("X:AI").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: What happens if you turn on the macro recorder, change the column names, stop the macro recorder?

Answer (score 0):

Naming a range is pretty straightforward:

```
Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow).Name = "NamedRange1"
Range("AF2:AF" & lastrow).Name = "NamedRange2"
Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow).Name = "NamedRange3"
Range("AH2:AH" & lastrow).Name = "NamedRange4"
Range("AI2:AI" & lastrow).Name = "NamedRange5"
```